# DataGridView not loading data programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a Windows application where I get an input from a TextBox and add it to the DataGridView when user clicks on a Button (`Add`).

[image]

My problem is that when I add the text for the first time, it works fine and its added to the grid.
When I add new text, it's not added to the DataGridView.  Once the Form is closed and reopened with the same object then I am able to see it.

Code:

```
private void btnAddInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Data == null)
        Data = new List<Inputs>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtInput.Text))
    {
        Data.Insert(Data.Count, new Inputs()
        {
            Name = txtInput.Text,
            Value = string.Empty
        });
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter parameter value", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }

    txtInput.Text = "";
    gridViewInputs.DataSource = Data;
}
```

I am not sure what is causing the record not to be added to grid on second add button click.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Try using `gridViewInputs.DisplayMember = "Name";`.

Comment: Why are you using `Data.Insert()`, when you don't need to keep track of the index ?
I would use simple `Data.Add()` - It would also have performance advantage when having a very populated List, and when removing elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `DataGridView.DataSource` to **`null`** before setting a new one.
This would cause the DataGridView to refresh its content with the new data in the source `List<Inputs>`:
the underlying [**`DataGridViewDataConnection`**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,2404) is reset only when the `DataSource` reference is different from the current or is set to null.

Note that when you reset the `DataSource`, the **`RowsRemoved`** event is raised multiple times (once for each row removed).

I suggest to change the `List` to a [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.ComponentModel.BindingList%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2), because any change to the List will be reflected automatically and because it will allow to remove rows from the DataGridView if/when required: using a **`List<T>`** as DataSource will not allow to remove a row.

```
BindingList<Inputs> InputData = new BindingList<Inputs>();
```

You can always set the [AllowUserToDeleteRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertodeleterows?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) and [AllowUserToAddRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(VS.Properties);k(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView);k(Designer_System.Windows.Forms.Design.FormDocumentDesigner);k(VisualSelection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) properties to `false` if you don't want your Users to tamper with the grid content.

For example:

```
public class Inputs
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

internal BindingList<Inputs> InputData = new BindingList<Inputs>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = InputData;
}

private void btnAddInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string textValue = txtInput.Text.Trim();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textValue))
    {
        InputData.Add(new Inputs() {
            Name = textValue,
            Value = "[Whatever this is]"
        });
        txtInput.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid value");
    }
}
```

If you want to keep using a `List<T>`, add the code required to reset the `DataGridView.DataSource`:

```
private void btnAddInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textValue))
    {
        //(...)
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = InputData;
        txtInput.Text = "";
    }
    //(...)
```